# Using return just after res.render in app.js is considered a good practise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got an error saying 
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)`.

So i decided to put a return after each res.render or res.send. Will it be a problem?

Comment: This happens because there is some piece of code that executes asynchronously and tries to return response to client, even though a response has already been sent. Show your code and I can help you more.

Comment: Headers must be set before any content is sent to the client. `return` does not affect anything AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually that kind of error is because something is sending output to the client earlier than expected.
The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state,
but some function tried to set a header or statusCode.

The res object in Express is a subclass of Node.js also you can see documentation about server Response at [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

**You need to send header one time in one request will Solve your problem.**